# Instagram API - https://instagram.api-docs.io/

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I see that some existing apps use the functionalities provided by https://instagram.api-docs.io/ ,i.e. follow/unfollow POST methods.
Is it not a deprecated libriary? I cannot find any up to date documentation.
Example: [https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/api/v1/friendships/create/{param1}](https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/api/v1/friendships/create/%7Bparam1%7D)

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Facebook now own instagram.
The Instagram APIs and permissions are in the Facebook Dev docs.

[IG Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/)

Comment: But there is still a possiblity to use old API's. I tracked IOS apps using proxy. They posted to https://i.instagram.com. Do you know how to?